# How to get 2d correspondances for 3d cad model points for non textured objects?

Tags: opencv, real-time, tracking, opencv-solvepnp

I have to estimate a very accurate 6D Pose of regular shape objects (like blocks for construction ) without any textured. I have the 3D CAD model of the object, and I know roughly the coordinates of the blocks. So the camera is pointing down to the object and can use stereo cameras or [ZED](https://www.stereolabs.com/zed/)

I know roughly the coordinates on the object and the camera will be placed around 1m away from the object. I would like to use OpenCV `solvePnP` method and for that need to find the 2d correspondences of the scene image for 3D CAD model points of the objects.

I search and found this tutorial for [Real Time pose estimation of a textured object](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d2c/tutorial_real_time_pose.html)  but in my case the objects are nontextured. So I can not use such key descriptors like SURF or SIFT or ORB. And also I would like to use it in real-time and as input to take my camera input.

Hence, research in this area has focused on tracking using natural features, such as edge-based, optical flow-based,template-based, and keypoint-based. Is this relevant so I can find the 2d correspondences for 3d cad model points for non-textured objects like construction blocks and can get the 6D Pose?

Also, I know that exists Harris Corners, Hough Lines, Canny Edge, or Fast Corners descriptors but not sure if using them can track the object and find the 2D-3D points correspondences. Can I use them in [Real Time pose estimation of a textured object](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d2c/tutorial_real_time_pose.html) and modify the source code for real-time so I can track my non-textured objects? If yes what should I change in the source code and how to run it in real-time?

Any help would appreciate.

Comment: the only way I know is to render the CAD model from all possible/relevant sides, angles, camera distances (with an appropriate rendering method which renders only visible edges) and find the best fit in the 2D edge image of your actual camera.

Comment: I think stereo camera will not help, because of untextured objects. Structured light depth-cameras might help, as well as laser scanners, if the object material is appropriate. Then a 3D pose matching can be used (like iterative closest points) or 3d geometry keypoint extraction.

Comment: I can use a depth ZED camera. Would be that ok?

Comment: depends on texture/surface, whethet good 3d point cloud is generated

Comment: For using point clouds and 3D CAD model has already done it with Point registration and ICP. I was thinking about another solution od finding correspondences between 3D CAD model and 2D Image. No Point Clouds. Understand? And objects don't have any texture.

Comment: My application is for nontextured objects. Without any texture.